# hbm equivalent of @LazyGroup in hibernate 5.1.0

Tags: hibernate

Hibernate 5.1 has option for specifying fetch groups for lazy fields. (Of course this requires byte code enhancement). There is documentation for showing how to specify fetch group using @LazyGroup but could not find anything to mark lazy group in hbm.

```
@Basic( fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
@LazyGroup( "lobs" )
private String name;

hbm : <property name="name" type="string" lazy="true" ???="lobs">
<column name="name" />
</property>
```

what would be the attribute name to replace "???" ?.  lazygroup="lobs" does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got to learn that lazygroup is not supported in hbm.
See here https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1043183